# How to display liquid content in show.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, liquid

I am working on an app in rails 5 and my goal is to displays products on pages show page using liquid.

page.rb

```
def to_liquid
  Product.all
end
```

product.rb

```
belongs_to :category
def to_liquid
  {  'name' => self.name,
      'price' => self.price,
      'description' => self.description,
      'category' => self.category
  }
end
```

category.rb

```
has_many :products

  def to_liquid
  {  'name' => self.name}
  end
```

show.html.erb (Page)

```
<%= RedCloth.new(Liquid::Template.parse(@page.content).render('page' => @page)).to_html %>
```

_form.html.erb(page)

```
<%= form_with(model: page, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if page.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(page.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this page from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% page.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In the text area for the content if I add the below text

```
Test for liquid in rails
{% for product in page.products %}
*{{ product.name }}* {{ product.price }}
Category: {{ product.category.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

on the show page only "Test for liquid in rails" appears but the products don't appear. Please help me figure out where I am going wrong I am completely new to liquid.

Instead of defining to_liquid I was using liquid_methods in the model but I get an error undefined method `liquid_methods so I found on stackoverflow to define to_liquid. I am following a tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/118-liquid?autoplay=true

Comment: that tutorial is 10 years old, better stick to the examples in the readme https://github.com/Shopify/liquid

Comment: @phoet I am able to get the desired out in the rails c using **@template = Liquid::Template.parse("hi {{name}}") @template.render('name' => 'tobi')**  but the desired out i want on show.html.erb(pages) as described above it doesnt work. Have I defined the to_liquid correctly in the page model?

Comment: just guessing here, but i think `to_liquid` is just any method that returns a hash which in turn is used for context in the liquid render function. so i assume that you would have to `render(@page.to_liquid)` to pass the context correctly